# ¿Como reproducir videos de youtube en Xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin.android, youtube

estoy intentando reproducir un video desde YouTube en Xamarin android, e podido reproducir vídeos utilizando webview pero no puedo utilizar controles como play, alguien podria ayudarme o darme informacion, me gustaria utilizar algo como Videoview pero no puedo reproducir videos streaming

Aclaro soy nuevo programando en Android

e intentado esto:

```
    string ID = "4Ec1NsEoKZ4";

        // CARGAR EL ENLACE
        Browser.HeightRequest = 1000;
        Browser.WidthRequest = 1000;
        // Browser.Source = cadena;
        Browser.Source = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ftqtdcKQA5A?rel=0&autoplay=1";

        //Browser.Source = "http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=" + ID;

        //---------------------------------------------------------- BOTON SIGUIENTE
        BTN_SIG.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            ID = "irQ1NhpPoJs";
            Browser.Source = "https://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=" + ID ;

            Browser.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;

        };
```

Comment: has intentado hacer algo? nos lo muestras?

Comment: ya lo mostré arriba. E intentado poner autoplay desde el enlace de youtube pero no funciona, solo carga el video pero no lo reproduce

Comment: Necesito que se reproduzca en automatico